# login into android app via google

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have a problem with loging into android app.

I try implementing this in my app, but I was try looking for "library" or function example.. I try download some project from github and launch in device, but unsuccesfull.. app stard but when I try login, select account and nothing.. some application write on toast "not log in" some not.. and I can't login into app via google..

For last I try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2XgERPfMcU this.

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services same "error"

I try 5-6 projects. The same problem..

I thing so problem it's in my phone, but I don't know where,thise app permissions not want not special..

Please help :)

I try on 2 mobiles. 
Xiaomi Mi3, Xiaomi Mi4

---

or I need write some ID's in downdload projects? or:...

Comment: Your english was difficult to understand. did you enable Google Sign-In in the Firebase console: ?

Comment: sorry, I want implement login google sign-in into my app, but projects not work for me, and I don't know how.

Comment: what is the ptroblem you are facing? Saying not working is too generic

Comment: login.. I try a lot project's from internet (2 example up)  but when launch app in mobile device i select account which want login but not login. but I not modify downloaded project i only import and start in device.. but i don't know why

Comment: Did you enable Google Sign-In in the Firebase console: ?

Comment: In download project I not implement my firebase.  my firebase implement via generate new json file ... and pacage this project it's com.google.samples.quickstart.signin ... not mine, I can't put thise into my firebase.

Comment: please try launch thise project https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services in your mobile and write if work good or not

Comment: you still have to create a account in firebase , then add the firebase credentials to your android project. Did you do that?